# Notification(jquery) not popping user message

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to fetch title and post to notification??..The title of notification is taken from the form and popped with notification. So when user clicks on submit button the duration and title is fetched and notification slide exists till the duration specified. I have posted the code...if possible please rectify it. If you have a b8r alternative plzz post it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    time: {
                          required: true,
                           number: true
                          },
                    title: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    time: "Please enter time(digit) in Seconds",
                    title: "Please enter the title"                
                }
            });
    
    

    $("#notify").hide();
    
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        if($('#form').valid()) {
            $("#notify").slideDown();

            var timeOut = parseInt($("#time").val())*1000 ; 
            var str = parseInt($("#title").val());

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#notify").slideUp();
            }, timeOut, str);
        }

            return false;
        });

    
    });
```

```css
#notify
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00FF00;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}


#message
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#form .formelement
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 900px;
}

#form .formelement label{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 110px;
}

#form .submit {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
}

#form .formelement label.error {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 0 10px 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="valid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />



<div id="notify">
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>

<fieldset>


<form action="" id="form" >

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="time">Time(in Sec) : </label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time"/>
            </div>

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="title">Title : </label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
            </div>
 
                    
            <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="Show Success" class="submit" id="s"/>
            </div>


</form> 
</fieldset>




</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems. First, you're missing a closing parenthesis on your second from last line of javascript.

Second, you're including jquery.min.js twice. Since validate.js was attached to the first one, the second one won't have access to the plugin. Remove the last loading of jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                time: "required",           
            },
            messages: {
                time: "Please enter Time in Miliseconds",                  
            }
        });

        $("#notify").hide();

        $("#form").submit(function(e) {
            $("#notify").slideDown();

            var timeOut = parseInt($("#time").val()); 

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#notify").slideUp();
            }, timeOut);

            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
#notify
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FF0000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: none;
}


#message
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
#form .formelement
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 900px;
}

#form .formelement label{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 110px;
}

#form .submit {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 40px;
}

#form .formelement label.error {
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 0 10px 100px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="notify">
    <div id="message">SUCCESSFULL</div>
</div>

<fieldset>



<form action="" id="form" method="post" >

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="time">Time (in Ms): </label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time"/>
            </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="Show Success" class="submit" />
            </div>



</form> 
</fieldset>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
i have 1 more doubt to b cleared..if in case i want to pop a message which is taken from user via form and pop it on submit then what will be the procedure?? A short descrpiton on how to go abt it will b appreciated :-)

Comment: I have modified the code according to my new requirement...plz suggest me some changes to make it work.